# How to validate a file select button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I prepared a form in angularjs and also done validations to it but i failed to do it for file select ,can anyone suggest help please.Thanks.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group" style="height:58px;" show-errors>

            <label class="control-label col-sm-12" >Please Attach The Documents <span class="error_red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--                    <input  name="picFile" type="button"  value="Select Picture" class="btn btn-default btn-file"  required accept="image/*">-->
                <input id="c" name="picFile" type="file" class="form-control" ngf-select="vm.uploadDocument($files,'logo')" ng-model="picFile" aria-required="true" required accept="image/*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img ng-if='vm.institution.logo'  ng-src="{{vm.config.imagePath}}modules/upload/institution/{{vm.institution.logo}}" alt="your image" style='width:50px;height:50px;'/>
            </div>    


            <div ng-messages="vm.form.institutionForm.picFile.$error" role="alert">
                <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Please select an image.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Define 'but I failed to do it for file select' ? What should it do?

Comment: _"i failed to do it"_ What is "it" and what's the problem?

Comment: I selected a file in add form and i saved it,then i tried editing it .....when i click on update button it says validation error for file select which i already selected in adding form.